# Inflate variable number of sublayouts inside a RecyclerView onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, flowlayout

I want to create an activity that looks similar to this:[image]

I will use a recyclerview to show all the questions. But each question has a variable number of clickable tags. The number of tags will vary and their width will also vary. Hence, I am using a FlowLayout in which I shall place the clickable tags. Typically I would have to use addview multiple times by looping on the number of tags. Is it possible to do this in the OnCreateViewHolder? How do I pass the information on the number of times the addview method is to be called to the onCreateViewHolder?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, on an `OnCreateViewHolder` method override, you just inflate a layout from resources and then construct a `ViewHolder` instance passing in that layout and whatever parameter it needs (in your case, the tags). The constructor of the `ViewHolder` class can then create any additional view(s), set their values and add it to the passed in layout.